# Add KeyListener and Draw To Screen in All Apps on Android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native

I have a pretty nice idea to implement. 
What I need is to somehow add a keylistener to the keyboard at all apps and to draw on all app's screens, including the browsers. Which means that I need to override the native keyboard and the native screen. Preferably in Java (I don't know if there is another language for Andoird, Java is the best one I know).

Could someone suggest me a way to override native keyboard\screen on Android? (OR just to do what I need, whichever is correct.)

Here's a way to do it on Windows. Not tested though. http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

Edit: TextFieldListener is OK too and even better as long as it's global. I haven't thought about possibility to make a keylogger with such thing.

Edit 2: Here is the link for drawing on top of everything, I haven't reviewed it too yet: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a custom keyboard by implementing an `InputService`

Comment: That would only work if the user opted into using it, and even then only for situations where an `InputMethodService` is used.

Comment: Huh?! How could I miss this great answer? Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks I'll send you a cookie, meanwhile have this smily :) . If you could point me to a tutorial on how to set it globally, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The first answer was correct. However, with InputService it is possible to know what is around the cursor.

Comment: This answer is correct. It is possible to create a key listener on a custom keyboard on all apps.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, it is not possible to "somehow add a keylistener to the keyboard at all apps", for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. Such things are called [keyloggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging), and they are primarily the province of malware authors.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't think about it. However the idea is really nice, so maybe someone will answer with some hack. Meanwhile I'm not marking it as the final answer. If no one will let me know about some nice "hack", I'll mark the answer as "best". Thanks!

Comment: I think I had to ask about overriding something globally, which I will in a different thread.

Comment: How about Joseph's idea? I haven't tried it , but where is the border of a custom keyboard once we get user's permission to install the app with the keyboard? The idea actually makes sense.

Comment: @VitaliPom: I commented on his answer back on August 24 at 18:40.

Comment: @CommonsWare now I saw your comment there. Thanks to that comment I found this post https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/mjsi1rNm4-A which says that the guy who wrote it succeeded to override the key events (of course with user permission). Am I missing something? I mean, I haven't time to try to override the key events yet and now I'm starting to believe that this answer is wrong.

Comment: @VitaliPom: "Am I missing something?" -- you apparently missed the "it all works perfectly in ordinary text fields" part (i.e., it does not work elsewhere), and the part where it doesn't work in Firefox's in-app field replacements. IOW, the thread you linked to validates my point.

Comment: I wonder who up voted the answer except for me, but it is incorrect since with a custom keyboard it is possible.